# Show unwanted text in drodown which is not in a list

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, selected

I have two drop downs

1:drop down having "Alpha-bates" and "Numeric"

2:drop dwon having X,Y,Z

if i select First drop down as Numeric. i need to show "NA" in 2nd dropdown

My Code:

```
 $("#Dropdwon").val("NA");
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. i don't want add to dropdown, just show that's it..!

Comment: Then your question is unclear. Try to clarify by putting here code actually producing your example dropdown, and then exactly what you want to happen to it.

Comment: I have updated my Question. Please check and help me Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
// first dropdown #Dropdown1
// second drop down #Dropdown2
```

Your requirement depend on first dropdown selection so you need to create event for Dropdown1 Selection, you need them to check value of it to be no a NAN then if Dropdown2 contains option for NA do nothing or append that option with class id NA to it.

```
$("#Dropdown1").on("select",function(){
if(!isNaN($(this).val(){
if($("Dropdown2").children("#NA").length==0){
$("Dropdown2").append("<option id='NA'>NA</option>");
}
}
```

Comment: jQuery object will never be undefined.